# How would you derivative the Binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, derivatives, binomial-coefficients

Im trying to find the value of $p$ that will maximize $P(X=k)$
So i was thinking i sould derivative the probability mass function

$\frac{d}{dp}{n \choose k}\cdot p^{k}\cdot(1-p)^{n-k}=0$

but i cant think of any idea how to start.
Im only getting to this : 
$k{n \choose k}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-k}-{n \choose k}p^{k}\left(n-k\right)\left(1-p\right)^{n-k-1}=0$

after some calculation Im getting closer to this:

$\frac{k}{n-k}=\frac{p}{1-p}$

$p=\frac{k}{n}$

Thank you for the help in the comment section..

Comment: The derivative is correct except for the plus sign, which is actually a minus sign (you need to derive $(1-p)$ also in the second term).

Comment: Thank you . Im getting to something really close i think

Comment: Just solve for $p$ now. It's a standard first degree equation. As a general rule, never bring your unknown at the denominator, if you don't need to.